# Is there a way to have PostgreSQL consider the Interpunct character · as a letter?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on an application storing strings of [the Gallo language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallo_language). In this language [the Interpunct character ·](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct) is considered a letter, not a word divider.

So I want for instance the query

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE sentence ~* '\m·r'
```

to return records where `sentence` contains word starting with `·r`.

Is there a way to force PosgresSQL to consider this Interpunct character ·  as a letter?

Comment: Is there a locale for the Gallo language?  If so, setting LC_CTYPE or Ctype appropriately should make PostgreSQL do the right thing automatically.

Comment: I don't think there is but I'm not sure where to find an official list of locales supported by PostgreSQL. I've found https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CHARSET-SUPPORTED but it's a list of character sets. Is is the place I should look at, or is there another official list?

Comment: I couldn't find one either, but not knowing much about the language it is possible I would see the abbreviation for it and just not recognize it.  But PostgreSQL uses the OS's facilities for localization, so you would be looking in glibc or ISO or ICU or the docs for your operating system, not in PostgreSQL itself.

Answer (score 1):

Phew... took ages, but I finally figured it out! It's a bit of a hack, but it was the only way I could find to do it.

My train of thought went like this:

SELECT ASCII('·'); Result: 183

After a lot of experimentation (see exhaustive fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dfee78ae9d1218e7da64aa66f1fc312a)), I came up with this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT CHR(112) || CHR(104) || CHR(183) || CHR(97) AS my_string
)
SELECT my_string FROM cte;
```

Result:

```
my_string
ph·a
```

which, as you can see, contains an interpunct character. I was forced to use the ASCII number representations because [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/) doesn't appear to treat · - interpunct - as a "proper" letter.

So, then I did this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT CHR(112) || CHR(104) || CHR(183) || CHR(97) AS my_string
)
SELECT 'ph·a' ~* (SELECT my_string FROM cte) AS test_result;
```

Result:

```
test_result
t
```

Which is the correct answer.

I know that it's a lot of trouble to go to (believe me, I was beating my head off the table betimes! :-) ), but it was the only way that I could figure it out. It is **possible** that with the right character set (utf8mtb4) or similar, interpunct may be treated as a proper letter - but it's the best I could do for the moment! HTH & A+! p.s. +1 for the question BTW, v. interesting and I learnt a lot! :-)

Comment: You don't really need the sub-select.  `select 'ph·a' ~* CHR(112) || CHR(104) || CHR(183) || CHR(97)` will work just as well or `select 'ph·a' ~* 'ph'||CHR(183)||'a'`

Comment: True enough - but I'm really trying to lay the groundwork for this to be done with a series of records where the location of the interpunct character isn't known in advance - I'm trying to work on either a) some sort of `WITH RECURSIVE` scheme or else string/array manipulation using PostgreSQL's [string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html) and [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html) functions.

Comment: @Vérace thank you very much for your help, much appreciated! I'm not sure how to apply your solution to the example query I've put in my question. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: Well, as you can see from my response to @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm actually trying to apply it in a generic fashion to a series of records in a table. If you feel that my answer was helpful, you could upvote it :-) and I'll try  and come up with a generic solution tomorrow. There's not much point in applying a solution to a string whose composition is known in advance... watch this space A+! p.s. it is possible that some sort of solution with locale and/or character sets might do the trick - but I would like to see if it's possible to solve this without resorting to changing system settings.

Comment: See the last entry in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f4aabb0c33be610a3b8da6743ee97bae). I believe that it does what you want?

Comment: Thanks Vérace, I've upvoted your answer. In [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=023d80acb4ba10d0d45826e2eeceb483) I was hoping the last query would return the records with id 4 and 5, but it does not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Finally resolved!. There is some sort of bug/feature that you have to concatenate the empty string to your search pattern in order to find words beginning with "·r". You have to write `WHERE sentence ~* ('' || '·r');` in order to get the SQL to work. Quite why this is, I don't know - I think I might file a bug report tomorrow - (il devient tard ici a Dublin!). Take a look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dab9572e37c823d02622844e242a059f) and see does it help resolve your problems - I hope it does and to get a correct vote! :-) Give me one, and I'll write it up!

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts  I still can't not make it work though, see my 3 queries in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f2f568683975e285e15b6bb3cf921bcc)

Comment: I think we can neglect the idea of CHAR(xxx) and rather go with [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d0f97277330c0084792f2b82076085f2), You can have when "·r" starts the entire sentence (SELECT * FROM records WHERE sentence ~* ('^' || '·r');`` or if "·r" starts a word within the sentence (`SELECT * FROM records WHERE sentence ~* ('\M' || '' || '·r');`) - or you could combine them - Voilà - les jeux sont faits! I think that provides as comprehensive an answer as you're going to get - why adding empty strings is necessary is beyond me (wild guess on my part  -- will report) - HTH

Comment: This is my final [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=419541d67e833cc9c72103e48aa0ff40) - you have all three possibilities within! A+

Comment: Thanks Vérace. I can't find a version of the query `SELECT * FROM records WHERE sentence ~* ('\M' || ' ' || '·r');` that would also return "·record qui commence un mot!".